# How to seperate rows based on the value of the first column from a csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file. The first column is user_id.

For example:

```
 User_ID    Latitude    Longitude
1   55.75672775 37.61538506
1   55.75286376 37.62190819
1   47.60760975 -122.334137
1   40.74881754 -73.99116039
2   40.72046126 -74.00974274
2   41.56305944 -70.65380573
2   41.56302733 -70.65389156
2   41.5542606  -70.60093403
2   44.55035619 -69.63040352
```

I want to run some functions for each unique user. Say, record all the locations that the user had.
So I want to do something like:

```
For each user_id:
    For row in all the rows of this user:
        Do something
        print user_id, result_output
```

I have no idea how to realize this.

Anyone could help me with this?

Comment: use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module

Comment: Don't forget t mark an answer as correct so people reading this in the future will know what worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) in the `CSV` module to combine the results, and then play:

```
import csv

data = {}

with open('filepath', 'r') as input:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input)

    for row in reader:
        try:
            data[row['user_id']].append((row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']))
        Except KeyError:
            data[row['User_ID'] = [(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'])]

for user_id in data:
    # do stuff with your tuples of longs and lats for each user_id
```

The `DictReader` takes your first row and uses it as the keys for each column.

Using this we can make a dict with the keys as your user ids and a list as a value. From there each time you encounter the user_id you just append a tuple of the longs and lats to the users list.

If your delimiter is something other than a comma, add the `delimter` argument to the `DictReader`. e.g.:

```
reader = DictReader(file, delimiter='\t')
```

And make sure the keys you use are exactly what Python finds in the header (there may be excess spaces, differences in capitalisation etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this (assuming your csv is tab delimited)

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('users.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')

    userdict = {}
    for line in reader:
        uid = int(line['User_ID'])
        if uid not in userdict:
            userdict[uid] = []
        userdict[uid].append({k: float(v) for k,v in line.iteritems() if k != 'User_ID'})

    for k, v in userdict.iteritems():
        print 'User %d has been to' % k
        for loc in v:
           print 'lat=%f long=%f' % (loc['Latitude'], loc['Longitude'])
```

The first part creates a `dict` which is keyed by the user id (converted to int) and the value is a list of all the latitude/longitude pairs for that user (converted to float).

The dict looks like

```
{1: [{'Latitude': 55.75672775, 'Longitude': 37.61538506}, {'Latitude': 55.75286376, 'Longitude': 37.62190819}, {'Latitude': 47.60760975, 'Longitude': -122.334137}, {'Latitude': 40.74881754, 'Longitude': -73.99116039}], 2: [{'Latitude': 40.72046126, 'Longitude': -74.00974274}, {'Latitude': 41.56305944, 'Longitude': -70.65380573}, {'Latitude': 41.56302733, 'Longitude': -70.65389156}, {'Latitude': 41.5542606, 'Longitude': -70.60093403}, {'Latitude': 44.55035619, 'Longitude': -69.63040352}]}
```

The second part which uses the created dict, prints all the coordinates that each user has been to. So you get output like

```
User 1 has been to
lat=55.756728 long=37.615385
lat=55.752864 long=37.621908
lat=47.607610 long=-122.334137
lat=40.748818 long=-73.991160
User 2 has been to
lat=40.720461 long=-74.009743
lat=41.563059 long=-70.653806
lat=41.563027 long=-70.653892
lat=41.554261 long=-70.600934
lat=44.550356 long=-69.630404
```

You could possibly save on using a dict by having the latitude, longitude pair represented by a tuple.

**Tuple version (with defaultdict to boot!)**

```
import csv
import itertools
import collections

with open('users.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')

    userdict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in reader:
        userdict[int(line['User_ID'])].append((float(line['Latitude']), float(line['Longitude'])))

    for k, v in userdict.iteritems():
        print 'User %d has been to' % k
        for loc in v:
           print 'Lat=%f Long=%f' % loc
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to iterate over the user ids, you going to need to know what they are in advance — which will require reading the whole file once ahead of time:

To find all the rows for a particular user id, you're again going to have to read the whole file again to pull all of them out. It also means you're going to need to do this multiple times, once per each unique user id. Be sure the file is opened and closeed the file properly each iteration. The `with` statements below ensure that this happens.

Here you go (assumes your csv file is tab-delimited):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

filename = 'user_data.csv'

with open(filename, 'rb') as user_data:
    reader = csv.reader(user_data, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader)  # skip header
    user_ids = set(row[0] for row in reader)

for user_id in sorted(user_ids):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as user_data:
        reader = csv.reader(user_data, delimiter='\t')
        next(reader)  # skip header
        for row in (row for row in reader if row[0] == user_id):
            pass  # do something
```